# Array Values Are Lost From JS To Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am attempting to pass array values from my JavaScript to my C# Controller.  I use console.log(); and verify that on the JavaScript side of things the values are exactly as expected.

However, when I add a breakpoint on the controller side (C#) - it shows me that updateData: Count = 0.  Why am I going from JavaScript having results to C# not having results?

```
$('#UpdateDB').click(function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ updateData: updateData }));
    $.ajax('https://localhost:44328/api/DBUpdate', {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { updateData: updateData },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert("save successfully!");
        }
    });
});
```

```
[Route("api/DBUpdate")]
public ActionResult UpdateDB(List<TLSModel> updateData)
{
    return Json(new { status = "success", message = "Records saved successfully" });
}
```

**EDIT**
This is what my TLSModel looks like

```
public class TLSModel
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public double StoreNumber { get; set; }
  public string StoreName { get; set; }
  public bool ActiveStore { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just pass in `ajax data:JSON.stringify({ updateData: updateData })`

Comment: @jishansiddique - same issue.  When it hits my controller the count = 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the model binder is expecting a list whereas looking at your comments you are sending an object which has a property which is a list.  Send it just the array and it will work.

Here is an example that works.

```
var updateData = [{ storeNumber: "2059", activeStore: false }, { storeNumber: "2005", activeStore: false }];

$('#UpdateDB').click(function () {      
    $.ajax('https://localhost:44328/api/DBUpdate', {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(updateData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert("save successfully!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your data type for the parameter of this function:

```
public ActionResult UpdateDB(List<TLSModel> updateData)
```

`List<TLSModel>` may not be matching/mapping correctly to the model you are passing into the C#.

Try `Array<TLSModel>`

If indeed the breakpoint is being hit in the C# code, the route is fine, so that's a good start.

I would try seeing if you can pass that updateData object into ANY controller function, and then see what happens if you pass just a string into ANY controller function, that could help narrow things down.

Comment: This is the output of my console.log();  am i sending it in the wrong format?  `{"arraCheck":[{"storeNumber":"2059","activeStore":false},{"storeNumber":"2005","activeStore":false}]}`

Comment: @JamesL you should add what you are posting as your model to your question. That is likely where the issue is. Also, please make sure it is exactly what is being posted and not a paraphrasing of the data.

Comment: @CPerson - you mean what the console.log() produces?

Comment: If I cahnge it to Array<TLSModel> I get this compile error `The Non-Generic Type Array can not be used with type arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm that updateData are an array in JS?

Otherwise try in your ajax post

```
data: { updateData: [updateData] }
```

Comment: This is the output of my console.log();  am i sending it in the wrong format?  `{"arraCheck":[{"storeNumber":"2059","activeStore":false},{"storeNumber":"2005","activeStore":false}]}`

Comment: The model you are sending looks wrong to me. Try sending in this instead of updateData variable: var tlsArray = [
            {
                ID: 0,
                StoreNumber: 12,
                StoreName: 'name',
                ActiveStore: true
            }, 
            {
                ID: 1,
                StoreNumber: 13,
                StoreName: 'name2',
                ActiveStore: true
            }];

Comment: if I change the data in my updateDB button click to read like this `data: { "arraCheck": [{ "storeNumber": "2059", "activeStore": false }, { "storeNumber": "2005", "activeStore": false }] },` when I hit the breakpoint in my controller code it is still null

Comment: Where does arraCheck come from? Use My output inspelad. Should work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cGay3Y

Though I noticed the array object in my example looks like this:

```
[{"storeNumber":"2059","activeStore":false},{"storeNumber":"2059","activeStore":false}]
```

Comment: I altered my controller method to be like this `UpdateDB(TLSModel[] updateData)` - but still the same issue, when I hover over updateData in the Controller it shows Count = 0...When I get to my Controller code, how would I iterate over updateData to confirm the data it contains?

Comment: Have you tried copying the exact code (all of it) in my example and see if that works at least (meaning, count is not 0)?